# Electromagnetism and static electricity

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

What is the difference between electromagnetism and static electricity? Also electromagnetic waves are mediated by photons , what mediates static electricity?

Comment: Electromagnetism is a fundamental force of nature. Static electricity is not. It is an accumulation of electric charge, and is 'mediated' by charged particles (typically electrons).

Answer (score 2):

Static electricity is a subfield of classical electromagnetism, the theory of electrically charged particles as well as electric and magnetic fields.

Photons only enter the picture in the quantum version of the theory, Quantum Electrodyanimcs (QED). EM waves are not *mediated* by photons, but EM waves and (real) photons are one and the same thing.

Static electricity is mediated by electric fields, which is described in the quantized theory as a *superposition* (more precisely a "coherent state") of a lot of photons. These are not quite the "regular" photons that make up EM waves though, but rather "virtual" ones.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Neuneck's answer.
Static electricity is a subfield of classical electromagnetism, the theory of electrically charged particles as well as electric and magnetic fields.

Photons only enter the picture in the quantum version of the theory, Quantum Electrodyanimcs (QED). EM waves are not mediated by photons, but EM waves and (real) photons are one and the same thing.

Comment: Yes,EM waves and (real) photons are one and the same thing.