# How does static electricity create waves in an electric field

Tags: electrostatics

How does static electricity create waves in an electric field in-between my hair and the balloon that I rubbed on my hair?  So why is my hair attracted to the balloon when I pull it away and there is space in-between them?

I've read [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/259628/static-electricity-what-is-it) answer which says that the source of electric field is the charge distribution in space.  And [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166794/electromagnetism-and-static-electricity) answer which says "Static electricity is mediated by electric fields, which is described in the quantized theory as a superposition (more precisely a "coherent state") of a lot of photons. These are not quite the "regular" photons that make up EM waves though, but rather "virtual" ones."   But I still don't understand how it creates waves. Or are waves created at all?  I can see how a moving current creates a wave, but not a static situation.

Answer (score 0):

> How does static electricity create waves in an electric field
>   in-between my hair and the balloon that I rubbed on my hair?

There are waves only when the baloon is moved from the hair to some distance to them. It is necessary some acceleration to change its location. The waves refresh the field so to speak.

After hair and ballon are in a new and fixed location, it is only a static electric field. No waves.